# What's the proper approach to variable swapping in Node 5.9 with ES6 syntax?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Node 5.9 loaded with `--harmony_destructuring` allows for most of the cool destructuring fun enabled by ES6. However, [this blog post](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth#destructuring) seems to indicate that I should be able to do variable swapping in the following manner:

```
var [a,b] = [0,1];
[b,a] = [a,b]; //swaps the values of a and b
```

However this fails in Node with an `invalid left-hand assignment` error. Instead I have to redefine the variables again:

```
var [a,b] = [0,1];
var [b,a] = [a,b];
```

Is the blog post flawed? Is this just an implementation detail of ES6 in Node?

Comment: *"Is this just an implementation detail of ES6 in Node?"* Yes. There is a reason why destructuring is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Blog post author here.*

Babel [compiles your code](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=var%20%5Ba%2Cb%5D%20%3D%20%5B0%2C1%5D%3B%0D%0A%5Bb%2Ca%5D%20%3D%20%5Ba%2Cb%5D%3B%20%2F%2Fswaps%20the%20values%20of%20a%20and%20b) as per what the article describes, into the following.

```
"use strict";

var a = 0;
var b = 1;
//swaps the values of a and b
var _ref = [a, b];
b = _ref[0];
a = _ref[1];
_ref;
```

You could use `babel-node` to attain this behavior in versions of Node that misbehave or are lacking one or two ES6 features.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing set of articles. Just going through each in detail to make sure I have this down. Thanks for putting the collection together!

Comment: FWIW node@6 reportedly will support destructuring properly: http://node.green/#destructuring--declarations